# Web.Api accept parameter form value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am using web.api 2.2, the client is sending the data in this style:

```
data={"kind": "Conversation", "tags": [], "items": [{"body": "hi there", "timestamp": "1445958749.284379", "kind": "MessageToOperator", "nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043", "visitor_nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043"}, {"body": "my name is amel and i am testing olark", "timestamp": "1445958753.320339", "kind": "MessageToOperator", "nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043", "visitor_nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043"}, {"body": "hi amel i am jessica", "timestamp": "1445958763.486881", "kind": "MessageToVisitor", "nickname": "Jessica Wood ", "operatorId": "744399"}, {"body": "ok im back", "timestamp": "1445959002.452643", "kind": "MessageToOperator", "nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043", "visitor_nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043"}, {"body": "hello there", "timestamp": "1445959059.642775", "kind": "MessageToVisitor", "nickname": "Jessica Wood ", "operatorId": "744399"}, {"body": "i ma here", "timestamp": "1445959066.829973", "kind": "MessageToOperator", "nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043", "visitor_nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043"}, {"body": "test", "timestamp": "1445959885.173931", "kind": "MessageToOperator", "nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043", "visitor_nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043"}, {"body": "hi there", "timestamp": "1445959894.323173", "kind": "MessageToVisitor", "nickname": "Jessica Wood ", "operatorId": "744399"}, {"body": "how are you doing", "timestamp": "1445959900.186131", "kind": "MessageToVisitor", "nickname": "Jessica Wood ", "operatorId": "744399"}, {"body": "Testing olark", "timestamp": "1445960829.592606", "kind": "MessageToOperator", "nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth)
#5043", "visitor_nickname": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043"}, {"body": "Hello there", "timestamp": "1445960834.471775", "kind": "MessageToVisitor", "nickname": "Jessica Wood ", "operatorId": "744399"}], "operators": {"744399": {"username": "winlotto.com", "emailAddress": "support@winnlotto.com", "kind": "Operator", "nickname": "Jessica Wood ", "id": "744399"}}, "visitor": {"city": "Rickmansworth", "kind": "Visitor", "conversationBeginPage": "http://www.winnlotto.com/", "countryCode": "GB", "ip": "195.110.84.183", "chat_feedback": {}, "operatingSystem": "Windows", "emailAddress": "", "country": "United Kingdom", "organization": "COLT Technology Services Group Limited", "fullName": "United Kingdom (Rickmansworth) #5043", "id": "tTOFv5oa0muGA16s7281C5P1GOAsjJA4", "browser": "Firefox 41.0"}, "isLead": "true", "id": "rWpAfF48ITi4y6DU7281C2R1GP0FHVJ3"}
```

See this **data=** in the start. They are sending json as a data parameter in value, which is funny, but I don't know how to accept it in web.api controller. I tried [FromBody] string data, it doesn't seem to work.

This is my action which accepts it:

```
[Route("Index")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Index([FromBody] string data)
        {
            var body = string.Empty;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
            {
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Edit:
What I did is crated model with string data field and it retrieves json in string:

```
public class ServiceModel
{
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

Is this correct way to retrieve form params?

Comment: does the request  reach  your server ?  or not ?  check with fiddler

Comment: Though you didn't mentioned, what are you getting into `body` with Stream reading?

Comment: it reaches the server. so they are basically not sending json but form. so for now i created model with 3

Comment: it does reach my server. what i actually created for now is a model with "string data" and it gets the json in string format but then i have to deserialize it into my model. is that correct way to do it?

Comment: @AmelSalibasic - They are sending an object using JSON format. You want to create an object that can be deserialized from the JSON string and accept this as the parameter in your method signature.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a model that represents the object you are expecting. The caller will send the object formatted as json, Web API can automatically deserialize this to a c# object. In that object you can then easily do validation on the model, do something with that data, and return a result which can also be automatically deserialized back to json (if that is what the caller wants).

I recommend you do some studying / reading up on core Web API concepts as this is fairly basic. What you do not want is to start implementing and supporting a solution that you do not fully understand. There are plenty of great resources out there, if you prefer hands on then search for some tutorials, if you prefer the finer details then start with a book or in depth explanation.

Here is some code to get you started. The classes are based on the JSON you provided.

```
public class Item {
   public string Body {get;set;}
   public string TimeStamp {get;set;}
   // rest of properties
}
public class SomeObject {
   public string Kind {get;set;}
   public string[] Tags  {get;set;}
   public Item[] Items {get;set;}
   // rest of properties
}


// your method in the web api controller
public IHttpActionResult Index([FromBody] SomeObject myObject) {
 // your validation and action code here and then return some result
}

// update your web api configuration registration to convert camel case json to pascal cased c# and back again
public static class WebApiConfig {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // makes all WebAPI json results lower case
            var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
// rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a [model binder](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) is the best way to go.

For example, let´s suppose I have this controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("bindingTest")]
public class BindingTestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Product data)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse();
    }
}
```

But the client is sending me the data in form-urlencoded format with the JSON data in the `data` parameter as you indicated :

```
client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
{ 
    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("data", "{'Id': 0,'Name': 'string'}") 
}));
```

Then I can create a custom model binder that reads such property, deserialized the `Product`object from JSON and sends the proper object to my action method in the controller:

```
// Raw prototype code
public class JsonFromDataVariable : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(Product))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("data");
        if (value != null && value.RawValue != null)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            var product = JsonSerializer
                                .Create()
                                .Deserialize<Product>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(value.RawValue.ToString())));
            bindingContext.Model = product;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public class JsonFromDataVariableProvider : ModelBinderProvider
{
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder(System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration configuration, Type modelType)
    {
        return new JsonFromDataVariable();
    }
}
```

Remember to indicate the binder in your model:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(JsonFromDataVariableProvider))]
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```